# Enforcing call to parent method

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

Is there anyway (or a pattern) to enforce a call to a parent method?

I have an abstract class like so:

```
abstract class APrimitive{
   public function validate(){
      //Do some stuff that applies all classes that extend APrimitive
   }
}
```

Then I have classes that extend upon the APrimitive "base":

```
class CSophisticated extends APrimitive{

   public function validate(){
       //First call the parent version:
       parent::validate();

       //Then do something more sophisticated here.
   }
}
```

The problem is that if we come back to the code in a few months time, and create a few more classes like CSophisticated with a `validate()` method, there is a possibility that we might forget to make a call to `parent::validate()` in that method.

Note that some CSophisticated classes may not have the `validate()` method, so the parent version will be called.

I understand that it is possible to just put in a comment somewhere, to remind the programmer to call `parent::validate()`, but is there a better way? Perhaps an automated way to throw an exception if the call to `parent::validate()` was not made in the `validate()` method would be nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enforce the call with the following:

```
abstract class APrimitive{
   final public function validate(){
      //do the logic in validate
      overrideValidate();
   }
   protected function overrideValidate(){
   }
}

class CSophisticated extends APrimitive{

   protected function overrideValidate(){

   }
}
```

Now only calls to `validate` are permitted, which will in turn call your overridden method. The syntax may be a little off (`PHP` is not my language of choice) but the principle is applyable to most OOP languages.

FURTHER EXPLANATION:

```
abstract class APrimitive{
   public function validate(){
      echo 'APrimitive validate call.';
      overrideValidate();
   }
   protected function overrideValidate(){
   }
}

class CSophisticated extends APrimitive{

   protected function overrideValidate(){
       echo 'CSophisticated call.';
   }
}

CSophisticated foo;
foo.overrideValidate(); //error - overrideValidate is protected
foo.validate(); //
```

Output:

```
APrimitive validate call.
CSophisticated call.
```

The function call basically does the following:

```
foo.validate() -> APrimitive.validate() -> ASophisticated.overrideValidate() (or APrimitive.overrideValidate() if it wasn't overriden)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that sometimes classes that implement APrimitive might not have the `validate()` method, which means the parent version will be called.

Comment: @phpdev I don't see how that would be a problem. You call validate - if no implementation is defined, validate() from APrimitive will be called (which is what you want) which will call overrideValidate() from APrimitive (since the derived class doesn't override it) which does nothing.

Comment: The problem is that every object working with these classes should just call the method `validate()` instead of having to decide wiether to call `overrideValidate()` or `validate()`;

Comment: You didn't understand the concept. You ALWAYS call validate(). overrideValidate() is protected, you shouldn't even be able to call it. It is called internally by validate(). The only difference is that you no longer override validate() in your derived classes, you override overrideValidate(), but from the outside, you always call validate().

Comment: @phpdev I edited my answer with some further info, hope you understand now.

Comment: What's to stop people subclassing and implementing their own validate() method that doesn't call the overrideValidate() method?  Not sure if PHP supports final methods but if it does then you must declare validate() as final to prevent it being overridden.

Comment: @GordonM agreed, but I'm not a PHP dev, it should have something like final or sealed.

Comment: @gordonM apparently the final keyword exists in PHP5, I edited my answer.

Comment: Ah that explains things. Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for [The Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern.
This pattern allows you to modify an operation in some way through sub-classing but ensures that the base class is always involved.

```
class Base {
    //declared final so it can't be overridden
    public final function validate() {

        //perform base class operations here

        //then forward to the sub class
        $this->doValidate();

        //do some more base class stuff here if needed

    }

    //override this method to alter validate operation
    protected function doValidate(){
        //no-op in base
    }
}

class Sub {
    protected function doValidate() {
        //if required
        //make the sub-class contribution to validate here
    }
}
```