# Silently call parent method behind my back

Tags: php, parent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enforcing call to parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005951/enforcing-call-to-parent-method)

I have a class like this

```
abstract class theme{

  abstract function header(){
    // do stuff here
  }

  abstract function footer(){
    // do stuff here

  }

}
```

so all child classes must have these 2 methods:

```
class Atheme extends theme{

  function header(){
    // do stuff here

    echo ..
  }

  function footer(){
    // do stuff here

    echo ..
  }

}
```

Now when I call one of these methods:

`$atheme = new Atheme;`

`$atheme->header();`

I want the header() method from the child class to automatically call the parent class header() method, without specifically calling parent::header() in the child class.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only one level of inheritance, you can accomplish this by doing something like:

```
abstract class theme {
    final public function header() {
        // do parent class stuff
        $this->_header();
    }

    abstract protected function _header();

    // ditto for footer
}

class Atheme extends theme {
    protected function _header() {
        // do child class stuff
    }
}
```

If the inheritance chain is arbitrarily long, then you'll need to use a [callback chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394986/php-oop-method-overriding-the-dry-way).